# Table of Derivatives looks better on Wolfram|Alpha

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting

I would like to reproduce the table format on the right side of the included image (Wolfram|Alpha) in Mathematica (left side).  How best to do this?

[image]

I copied the Mathematica code from  wolfram|alpha but the results look better in wolfram|alpha.

Answer (score 5):

```
Table[{n, D[Exp[s^a], {s, n}]}, {n, 1, 5}]

% // TableForm
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[{n, D[Exp[s^a], {s, n}]}, {n, 1, 5}] // 
  Prepend[{n, "\[PartialD]^n \[ExponentialE]^s^a / \[PartialD]s^n"}] //
  Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemStyle -> {{Bold}, {Bold, Black}}, 
   Background -> {{1 -> LightYellow}, {LightYellow}}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[
   {n, D[Exp[s^a], {s, n}] // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm},
   {n, 1, 5}] //
  Prepend[#, Style[#, 16] & /@ 
     TraditionalForm /@
      {n, Inactive[D][Exp[s^a], {s, n}]}] & //
  Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]